# How can I set the position of a drop down list with D3.js?

Tags: javascript, d3.js, drop-down-menu

I want to set the position of a drop down list with D3.js but unlike other elements, select element hasn't x and y attributes so I don't know how to do it.

```
d3.select("#chart")
             .append("select")
             .attr("id","desplegable")
             .on('change',onchange)
             .selectAll("option")
             .data(preguntas)
             .enter()
             .append("option")
             .attr("value", function(d){return d;})
             .text(function(d){return d;})
          ;
```

Moreover, I tried to insert the drop down list in a svg but it doesn't work.

```
var svg = d3.select("#chart").append("svg")
            .attr("id","svg")
            .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
            .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
            .append("g")
            .attr("transform",
                "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")"); 


   svg.append("select")
             .attr("id","desplegable")
             .on('change',onchange)
             .selectAll("option")
             .data(preguntas)
             .enter()
             .append("option")
             .attr("value", function(d){return d;})
             .text(function(d){return d;})
      ;
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: It has been fun following this question, it already has 2 upvotes, 1 answer... let's see how long it will take until people realise that one **cannot** append HTML elements like a `select` inside an SVG (unless using the cumbersome `foreignObject`).

Comment: That is a good point -- funny how I just glossed over the fact that the code is trying to do just that. I guess I was just trying to describe how I usually go about mixing html and svg elements on the same page...

Answer (score 0):

HTML elements (like your select/options input) are positioned using CSS styling -- typically by assigning a "class" (if you want to style several elements the same way), or by "id" (which must be unique within your html document).

So the simplest way to "position" your select list is by including directives like this in the `<style>` section of your page:

```
<style>
    #desplegable {
        left: 10px;
        top: 5px;
    }
</style>
```

Less desirable would be to just include those CSS directives right on the `select` element itself, using the d3 `style(name, value)` function:

```
svg.append("select")
   .attr("id","desplegable")
   .style("left", "10px")
   .style("top", "5px")
   ... etc ...
```

Generally, trying to pixel position html elements is an exercise in frustration -- for both you and your users with different resolution screens and devices. But if you need to give your element some margins or alignment, there are many css directives that should help you get it looking the way you want.

IMO, The easiest way to try out different styling is to use `F12` to open the browser's Dev Console -- when you find the element on the page, use the right-hand list of styles to interactively tweak it...